# Only need one package within metapackage

Tags: ros, package, metapackage

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How can a single package be selected from a metapackage rather than installing all packages within a metapackage?

Example: Geometry (http://ros.org/wiki/geometry). I only need tf.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62352/only-need-one-package-within-metapackage/) by [TJump](https://answers.ros.org/users/2785/tjump/) on ROS Answers with karma: 160 on 2013-05-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you are using the debian packages, simply install the package instead of the metapackage:

`sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-tf`

---

Originally posted by [rtoris288](https://answers.ros.org/users/982/rtoris288/) with karma: 1173 on 2013-05-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-05-07**:
This will only work for catkinized packages.

**Comment by [TJump](https://answers.ros.org/users/2785/tjump/) on 2013-05-07**:
I may have found the issue with this process on a BeagleBone. Apparently there are problems with checking out debian packages onto this ARM device.

**Comment by [TJump](https://answers.ros.org/users/2785/tjump/) on 2013-05-08**:
So how do we get individual "non-catkinized" packages for the ARM processor/BeagleB?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-05-08**:
You download them from source and delete the rest.